# Summing an array along different dim each time with different slice range

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Suppose I have an array `b` of shape `(3, 10, 3)` and another array `v = [8, 9, 4]` of shape `(3,)`, see below. For each of the 3 arrays of shape `(10, 3)` in `b`, I need to sum a number of rows as determined by `v`, i.e. for `i  = 0, 1, 2` I need to get `np.sum(b[i, 0:v[i]], axis=0)`. My solution (shown below) uses a for loop which is inefficient I guess. I wonder if there is an efficient (vectorized) way to do what I have described above.

NB: my actual arrays have more dimension, these arrays are for illustration.

```py
v = np.array([8,9,4])
b = np.array([[[0., 1., 0.],
               [0., 0., 1.],
               [0., 0., 1.],
               [0., 0., 1.],
               [1., 0., 0.],
               [1., 0., 0.],
               [0., 0., 1.],
               [1., 0., 0.],
               [0., 1., 0.],
               [1., 0., 0.]],

              [[0., 0., 1.],
               [0., 1., 0.],
               [1., 0., 0.],
               [0., 0., 1.],
               [1., 0., 0.],
               [1., 0., 0.],
               [1., 0., 0.],
               [0., 1., 0.],
               [0., 0., 1.],
               [0., 1., 0.]],

              [[1., 0., 0.],
               [1., 0., 0.],
               [1., 0., 0.],
               [0., 0., 1.],
               [0., 1., 0.],
               [0., 1., 0.],
               [1., 0., 0.],
               [1., 0., 0.],
               [0., 0., 1.],
               [1., 0., 0.]]])

n=v.shape[0]
vv=np.zeros([n, n])
for i in range(n):
   vv[i]=np.sum( b[i,0:v[i]],axis=0)
```

Output:

```py
vv
array([[3., 1., 4.],
       [4., 2., 3.],
       [3., 0., 1.]])
```

**Edit**: 
Below is more an actual example of the arrays v and b.

```py
v= np.random.randint(0,300, size=(32, 98,3))
b = np.zeros([98, 3, 300, 3])
for i in range(3): 
   for j in range(98):
       b[j,i] = np.random.multinomial(1,[1./3, 1./3, 1./3], 300)

v.shape
Out[292]: (32, 98, 3)

b.shape
Out[293]: (98, 3, 300, 3)
```

I need to do the same thing as before, so the final result is an array of shape `(32,98,3,3)`. Note that I have to do the above at each iteration that is why I'm looking for an efficient implementation.

Comment: Could you provide realistic numbers for the array dimensions so the performance can be checked / compared?

Comment: Sorry for replying late! I edited my question and now it includes the realistic numbers for the array dimensions as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a performance comparison of the different methods presented in the answers:

- [`sliced_reduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57048425/3767239)
- [`sliced_sum`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57085167/3767239)
- [`sliced_sum_numba`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57091315/3767239)
- [`reduce_cumulative`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57096233/3767239) (original idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57048467/3767239))
- `baseline` - The "classic" Python `for` loop (see below).

#### Notes on performance

- `sliced_reduce` reverses the order of index pairs from ascending to descending to turn the computation of superfluous elements to no-ops; this way however the array is not traversed in memory layout order and seems to slow down the method by ~30%.
- `reduce_cumulative` performs a number of unnecessary add operations which depends on the distribution of start and stop indices. For the OP example where start indices are all zero and stop indices are uniformly distributed this will be in average twice as many operations as strictly necessary. For other distributions (e.g. non-zero start indices) this fraction might very well change and hence degrade the performance as compared to other methods. Please check your own case.
- **[Disclaimer]** As with all performance estimations, these are rough guidelines to give a broad overview but they don't save you from running the performance tests yourself for your specific use case on your specific machine to be absolutely certain to select the best option.

Using the example dimensions from the OP:

```
In [15]: np.random.seed(0)

In [16]: b = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(98, 3, 300, 3))

In [17]: v = np.random.randint(-299, 300, size=(32, 98, 3))

In [18]: %timeit sliced_reduce(b, np.zeros_like(v), v, np.add, axis=2)
11.3 ms ± 110 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [19]: %timeit sliced_sum(b, np.zeros_like(v), v, axis=2)
54.9 ms ± 153 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [20]: %timeit sliced_sum_numba(b, np.zeros_like(v), v, 2)
16.3 ms ± 609 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [21]: %timeit reduce_cumulative(b, np.zeros_like(v), v, np.add, axis=2)
2.05 ms ± 30.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [22]: %timeit baseline(b, np.zeros_like(v), v, axis=2)
79 ms ± 625 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Baseline implementation:

```
def baseline(a, i, j, axis=None):
    if axis is None:
        axis = len(i.shape)
    i = (a.shape[axis] + i) % a.shape[axis]
    j = (a.shape[axis] + j) % a.shape[axis]
    m = len(i.shape) - axis
    result = np.empty(i.shape + a.shape[axis+1:], dtype=a.dtype)
    for k in np.ndindex(i.shape):
        result[k] = np.sum(a[k[m:] + (slice(i[k], j[k]),)], axis=0)
    return result
```

## Performance plots

Besides the timings for the OP's specific example case it is instructive to check how the algorithms scale with the size of the data and index arrays. Here we can separate the shapes into three different components:

- Leading dimensions of the index array (those that are not present in the data array). In the OP example this is `(32,)`.
- Common dimensions of the index and the data array (the dimensions after the leading ones up to the reduced axis). In the OP example this is `(98, 3)`.
- The size of the axis to be reduced. In the OP example this is `300`.
- (The trailing dimensions of the data array are handled similarly by all algorithms and hence no particular scaling is to be expected.)

Hence we can create performance plots for three different cases: Varying the size of the leading dimension(s), the common dimensions and the size of the axis to be reduced. Boundaries are chosen from `1` to `N` where `N` is the largest power of `2` such that no involved array has more than 5,000,000 elements (input, index, output; intermediary arrays might be larger (such as for `sliced_reduce`)).

For the code see below.

### Leading dimensions

[image: Performance scaling with size of leading dimensions]

### Common dimensions

[image: Performance scaling with size of common dimensions]

### Reduced dimension

[image: Performance scaling with size of reduced dimension]

### Code

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as symbols
import numba
import numpy as np
import perfplot

np.random.seed(0)

def sliced_reduce(a, i, j, ufunc=np.add, axis=2):
    indices = np.tile(
        np.repeat(
            np.arange(np.prod(a.shape[:axis])) * a.shape[axis],
            2
        ),
        np.prod(i.shape[:len(i.shape) - axis])
    )
    indices[::2] += (a.shape[axis] + i.ravel()) % a.shape[axis]
    indices[1::2] += (a.shape[axis] + j.ravel()) % a.shape[axis]
    indices = indices.reshape(-1, 2)[::-1].ravel()  # This seems to be counter-effective, please check for your own case.
    result = ufunc.reduceat(a.reshape(-1, *a.shape[axis+1:]), indices)[::2]  # Select only even to odd.
    result[indices[::2] == indices[1::2]] = ufunc.reduce([])
    return result[::-1].reshape(*(i.shape + a.shape[axis+1:]))

def sliced_sum(a, i, j, axis=2):
    l = len(i.shape) - axis
    m = len(i.shape) - l
    n = len(a.shape) - axis - 1
    leading = symbols[:l]
    common = symbols[l:l+m]
    summation = symbols[l+m]
    trailing = symbols[l+m+1:l+m+1+n]
    i = (a.shape[axis] + i) % a.shape[axis]
    j = (a.shape[axis] + j) % a.shape[axis]
    indices, i, j = np.broadcast_arrays(np.arange(a.shape[axis]),
                                        np.expand_dims(i, -1), np.expand_dims(j, -1))
    active_elements = (i <= indices) & (indices < j)
    return np.einsum(f'{leading + common + summation},{common + summation + trailing}->{leading + common + trailing}',
                     active_elements, a)

def sliced_sum_numba(a, i, j, axis=2):
    i = (a.shape[axis] + i) % a.shape[axis]
    j = (a.shape[axis] + j) % a.shape[axis]
    m = np.prod(i.shape[:len(i.shape) - axis], dtype=int)
    n = np.prod(i.shape[len(i.shape) - axis:], dtype=int)
    a_flat = a.reshape(-1, *a.shape[axis:])
    i_flat = i.ravel()
    j_flat = j.ravel()
    result = np.empty((m*n,) + a.shape[axis+1:], dtype=a.dtype)
    numba_sum(a_flat, i_flat, j_flat, m, n, result)
    return result.reshape(*(i.shape + a.shape[axis+1:]))

@numba.jit(parallel=True, nopython=True)
def numba_sum(a, i, j, m, n, out):
    for index in numba.prange(m*n):
        out[index] = np.sum(a[index % n, i[index]:j[index]], axis=0)

def reduce_cumulative(a, i, j, ufunc=np.add, axis=2):
    i = (a.shape[axis] + i) % a.shape[axis]
    j = (a.shape[axis] + j) % a.shape[axis]
    a = np.insert(a, 0, 0, axis)
    c = ufunc.accumulate(a, axis=axis)
    pre = np.ix_(*(range(x) for x in i.shape))
    l = len(i.shape) - axis
    return c[pre[l:] + (j,)] - c[pre[l:] + (i,)]

def baseline(a, i, j, axis=2):
    i = (a.shape[axis] + i) % a.shape[axis]
    j = (a.shape[axis] + j) % a.shape[axis]
    m = len(i.shape) - axis
    result = np.empty(i.shape + a.shape[axis+1:], dtype=a.dtype)
    for k in np.ndindex(i.shape):
        result[k] = np.sum(a[k[m:] + (slice(i[k], j[k]),)], axis=0)
    return result

a = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(98, 3, 300, 3))
j = np.random.randint(-299, 300, size=(32, 98, 3))
i = np.zeros_like(j)
check = [f(a, i, j) for f in [sliced_reduce, sliced_sum, sliced_sum_numba, reduce_cumulative, baseline]]
assert all(np.array_equal(check[0], x) for x in check[1:])

perfplot.show(
    # Leading dimensions:
    # setup = lambda n: (np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(98, 3, 300, 3)),
    #                    np.zeros((n, 98, 3), dtype=int),
    #                    np.random.randint(-299, 300, size=(n, 98, 3))),
    # Common dimensions:
    # setup = lambda n: (np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(n, 3, 300, 3)),
    #                    np.zeros((32, n, 3), dtype=int),
    #                    np.random.randint(-299, 300, size=(32, n, 3))),
    # Reduced dimension:
    setup = lambda n: (np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(98, 3, n, 3)),
                       np.zeros((32, 98, 3), dtype=int),
                       np.random.randint(-n+1, n, size=(32, 98, 3))),
    kernels=[
        lambda a: sliced_reduce(*a),
        lambda a: sliced_sum(*a),
        lambda a: sliced_sum_numba(*a),
        lambda a: reduce_cumulative(*a),
        lambda a: baseline(*a),
    ],
    labels=['sliced_reduce', 'sliced_sum', 'sliced_sum_numba', 'reduce_cumulative', 'baseline'],
    # n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(13)],  # Leading dimensions.
    # n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(11)],  # Common dimensions.
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(2, 13)],  # Reduced dimension.
    # xlabel='Size of leading dimension',
    # xlabel='Size of first common dimension (second is 3)',
    xlabel='Size of reduced dimension',
)
```

Comment: Wow, this is more detail than I was expecting! Much appreciated and many thanks for your well detailed answer. I am pretty sure this will help a lot of people out there.

Answer (score 1):

The following function allows for reducing a given axis with varying slices indicated by start and stop arrays. It uses [`np.ufunc.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) under the hood together with appropriately reshaped versions of the input array and the indices. It avoids unnecessary computations but allocates an intermediary array two times the size of the final output array (the computation of the discarded values are however no-ops).

```
def sliced_reduce(a, i, j, ufunc, axis=None):
    """Reduce an array along a given axis for varying slices `a[..., i:j, ...]` where `i` and `j` are arrays themselves.

    Parameters
    ----------
    a : array
        The array to be reduced.
    i : array
        Start indices for the reduced axis. Must have the same shape as `j`.
    j : array
        Stop indices for the reduced axis. Must have the same shape as `i`.
    ufunc : function
        The function used for reducing the indicated axis.
    axis : int, optional
        Axis to be reduced. Defaults to `len(i.shape)`.

    Returns
    -------
    array
        Shape `i.shape + a.shape[axis+1:]`.

    Notes
    -----
    The shapes of `a` and `i`, `j` must match up to the reduced axis.
    That means `a.shape[:axis] == i.shape[len(i.shape) - axis:]``. 
    `i` and `j` can have additional leading dimensions and `a` can have additional trailing dimensions.
    """
    if axis is None:
        axis = len(i.shape)
    indices = np.tile(
        np.repeat(
            np.arange(np.prod(a.shape[:axis])) * a.shape[axis],
            2  # Repeat two times to have start and stop indices next to each other.
        ),
        np.prod(i.shape[:len(i.shape) - axis])  # Perform summation for each element of additional axes.
    )
    # Add `a.shape[axis]` to account for negative indices.
    indices[::2] += (a.shape[axis] + i.ravel()) % a.shape[axis]
    indices[1::2] += (a.shape[axis] + j.ravel()) % a.shape[axis]
    # Now indices are sorted in ascending order but this will lead to unnecessary computation when reducing
    # from odd to even indices (since we're only interested in even to odd indices).
    # Hence we reverse the order of index pairs (need to reverse the result as well then).
    indices = indices.reshape(-1, 2)[::-1].ravel()
    result = ufunc.reduceat(a.reshape(-1, *a.shape[axis+1:]), indices)[::2]  # Select only even to odd.
    # In case start and stop index are equal (i.e. empty slice) `reduceat` will select the element
    # corresponding to the start index. Need to supply the correct default value in this case.
    result[indices[::2] == indices[1::2]] = ufunc.reduce([])
    return result[::-1].reshape(*(i.shape + a.shape[axis+1:]))  # Reverse order and reshape.
```

For the examples in the OP it can be used in the following way:

```
# 1. example:
b = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(3, 10, 3))
v = np.random.randint(-9, 10, size=3)  # Indexing into `b.shape[1]`.
result = sliced_reduce(b, np.zeros_like(v), v, np.add)

# 2. example:
b = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(98, 3, 300, 3))
v = np.random.randint(-299, 300, size=(32, 98, 3))  # Indexing into `b.shape[2]`; one additional leading dimension for `v`.
result = sliced_reduce(b, np.zeros_like(v), v, np.add, axis=2)
```

## Notes

- Reversing the order of flat index pairs in order to have `even < odd` and thus shortcut every second computation with a no-op doesn't seem to be a good idea (probably because the flattened array is not traversed in memory layout order anymore). Removing this part and using the flat indices in ascending order gives a performance increase of about 30% (also for the [perfplots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57091481/3767239), though not included there).

Comment: Thanks! Your solution looks efficient to me, though not sure how to apply it to the real arrays with the actual number of dimensions.

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks a lot @a_guest! That is exactly what I hoped for. Perfect.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a function in pytorch similar to np.add.reduceat to have a similar implementation for tensors.

Comment: @PJORR I added [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57085167/3767239) that works with `np.einsum` and hence is compatible with PyTorch (since they also implemented `torch.einsum`). It allows for summing along an axis (no generality like with ufunc here) hence it should suit your purpose. I added another answer since it's a distinct approach. Please have a look. I'm not aware of any function in PyTorch that is similar to `np.add.reduceat`.

Answer (score 1):

The following function allows for summing a given axis with varying slices indicated by start and stop arrays. It uses [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) under the hood together with an appropriately computed coefficient array that indicates which elements in the input array should participate in the sum (using coefficients `1` and `0`). Relying on `einsum` makes the implementation compatible with other packages such as [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.einsum) or [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum) (with minor changes). It doubles the number of necessary computations since for each add operation comes an additional multiply operation with the coefficient array.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as symbols
import numpy as np

def sliced_sum(a, i, j, axis=None):
    """Sum an array along a given axis for varying slices `a[..., i:j, ...]` where `i` and `j` are arrays themselves.

    Parameters
    ----------
    a : array
        The array to be summed over.
    i : array
        The start indices for the summation axis. Must have the same shape as `j`.
    j : array
        The stop indices for the summation axis. Must have the same shape as `i`.
    axis : int, optional
        Axis to be summed over. Defaults to `len(i.shape)`.

    Returns
    -------
    array
        Shape `i.shape + a.shape[axis+1:]`.

    Notes
    -----
    The shapes of `a` and `i`, `j` must match up to the summation axis.
    That means `a.shape[:axis] == i.shape[len(i.shape) - axis:]``. 
    `i` and `j` can have additional leading dimensions and `a` can have additional trailing dimensions.
    """
    if axis is None:
        axis = len(i.shape)

    # Compute number of leading, common and trailing dimensions.
    l = len(i.shape) - axis      # Number of leading dimensions.
    m = len(i.shape) - l         # Number of common dimensions.
    n = len(a.shape) - axis - 1  # Number of trailing dimensions.

    # Select the corresponding symbols for `np.einsum`.
    leading = symbols[:l]
    common = symbols[l:l+m]
    summation = symbols[l+m]
    trailing = symbols[l+m+1:l+m+1+n]

    # Convert negative indices.
    i = (a.shape[axis] + i) % a.shape[axis]
    j = (a.shape[axis] + j) % a.shape[axis]

    # Compute the "active" elements, i.e. the ones that should participate in the summation.
    # "active" elements have a coefficient of 1 (True), others are 0 (False).
    indices, i, j = np.broadcast_arrays(np.arange(a.shape[axis]),
                                        np.expand_dims(i, -1), np.expand_dims(j, -1))
    active_elements = (i <= indices) & (indices < j)
    return np.einsum(f'{leading + common + summation},{common + summation + trailing}->{leading + common + trailing}',
                     active_elements, a)
```

For the examples in the OP it can be used in the following way:

```
# 1. example:
b = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(3, 10, 3))
v = np.random.randint(-9, 10, size=3)  # Indexing into `b.shape[1]`.
result = sliced_sum(b, np.zeros_like(v), v)

# 2. example:
b = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(98, 3, 300, 3))
v = np.random.randint(-299, 300, size=(32, 98, 3))  # Indexing into `b.shape[2]`; one additional leading dimension for `v`.
result = sliced_sum(b, np.zeros_like(v), v, axis=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) to speed up the loop. This avoids unnecessary computations and memory allocation and is fully compatible with all `numpy` functions (i.e. also `prod` etc. work similarly).

```
import numba
import numpy as np

def sliced_sum_numba(a, i, j, axis=None):
    """Sum an array along a given axis for varying slices `a[..., i:j, ...]` where `i` and `j` are arrays themselves.

    Parameters
    ----------
    a : array
        The array to be summed over.
    i : array
        The start indices for the summation axis. Must have the same shape as `j`.
    j : array
        The stop indices for the summation axis. Must have the same shape as `i`.
    axis : int, optional
        Axis to be summed over. Defaults to `len(i.shape)`.

    Returns
    -------
    array
        Shape `i.shape + a.shape[axis+1:]`.

    Notes
    -----
    The shapes of `a` and `i`, `j` must match up to the summation axis.
    That means `a.shape[:axis] == i.shape[len(i.shape) - axis:]``. 
    `i` and `j` can have additional leading dimensions and `a` can have additional trailing dimensions.
    """
    if axis is None:
        axis = len(i.shape)
    # Convert negative indices.
    i = (a.shape[axis] + i) % a.shape[axis]
    j = (a.shape[axis] + j) % a.shape[axis]
    # Operate on a flattened version of the array (dimensions up to `axis` are flattened).
    m = np.prod(i.shape[:len(i.shape) - axis], dtype=int)  # Elements in leading dimensions.
    n = np.prod(i.shape[len(i.shape) - axis:], dtype=int)  # Elements in common dimensions.
    a_flat = a.reshape(-1, *a.shape[axis:])
    i_flat = i.ravel()
    j_flat = j.ravel()
    result = np.empty((m*n,) + a.shape[axis+1:], dtype=a.dtype)
    numba_sum(a_flat, i_flat, j_flat, m, n, result)
    return result.reshape(*(i.shape + a.shape[axis+1:]))

@numba.jit(parallel=True, nopython=True)
def numba_sum(a, i, j, m, n, out):
    for index in numba.prange(m*n):
        out[index] = np.sum(a[index % n, i[index]:j[index]], axis=0)
```

For the examples in the OP it can be used in the following way:

```
# 1. example:
b = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(3, 10, 3))
v = np.random.randint(-9, 10, size=3)  # Indexing into `b.shape[1]`.
result = sliced_sum_numba(b, np.zeros_like(v), v)

# 2. example:
b = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(98, 3, 300, 3))
v = np.random.randint(-299, 300, size=(32, 98, 3))  # Indexing into `b.shape[2]`; one additional leading dimension for `v`.
result = sliced_sum_numba(b, np.zeros_like(v), v, axis=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another idea, brought up by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57048467/3767239) (hence community wiki), is to use `np.cumsum` and then select the rows corresponding to the slice indices. One can deal with zero indices by inserting an additional zero-row at the beginning of the axis that is to be reduced. This approach performs unnecessary computations since it computes the full cumulative sum, beyond the final index. In case the stop indices are uniformly distributed along the axis (with median `input_array.shape[axis]//2`) this will in average perform twice as many add operations as necessary. Nevertheless this approach seems to [perform quite well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57091481/3767239) compared to other methods (at least for the dimensions indicated by the OP).

```
def reduce_cumulative(a, i, j, ufunc, axis=None):
    if axis is None:
        axis = len(i.shape)
    i = (a.shape[axis] + i) % a.shape[axis]
    j = (a.shape[axis] + j) % a.shape[axis]
    a = np.insert(a, 0, 0, axis)  # Insert zeros to account for zero indices.
    c = ufunc.accumulate(a, axis=axis)
    pre = np.ix_(*(range(x) for x in i.shape))  # Indices for dimensions prior to `axis`.
    l = len(i.shape) - axis  # Number of leading dimensions in `i` and `j`.
    return c[pre[l:] + (j,)] - c[pre[l:] + (i,)]
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, here's a one-liner.  No promises that this is the most efficient version, because it does a lot more addition than necessary:

```
In [25]: b.cumsum(axis=1)[np.arange(b.shape[0]), v-1]                                                          
Out[25]: 
array([[3., 1., 4.],
       [4., 2., 3.],
       [3., 0., 1.]])
```

(Also be aware that it doesn't correctly handle a 0 in `v`.)

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I do have zeros in `v`.